# Trying to find an older anime about a man who morphs into a robot/mecha suit

Tags: story-identification, aliens, anime, cartoon, mecha

There was this cartoon/anime I used to watch as a kid on a VHS tape that I cannot for the life of me remember the name of. What I remember from this show/movie was that:

1. It was set in space.
2. The MC was a man who was able to morph into a robot, possibly a mecha-suit.
3. The sequence of him transforming into this robot involved his body and limbs being wrapped in wires while a voiceover described what happened and who he was turning into. I believe the background was mostly red during this sequence and the wires and MC were grayscale.
4. There was a sidekick/younger-brother-ish character who was kind of annoying, he had an annoying voice, and he wanted to turn into the robot too, but I think he couldn't because he was too young or something like that.
5. There was a villain (possibly the main villain) that was an alien that had a Gilbert-Gottfried-type of voice.
6. There was a small, floating alien character who I believe was a sidekick to the either the MC or the villain. It had a mouth that looked like a style and stigma of a flower and it had a high-pitched voice.
7. I watched it as a kid (late 90s to early 2000s), and my dad said he watched it when he was younger as well, so it had to be from anytime from the 60s to maybe even the 90s.

Unfortunately, that is as much as I can remember. I really want to find out the name of this cartoon/anime so I can rewatch it and feel at peace knowing that I found it again.

Answer (score 8):

Well... thankfully I posted this to Facebook, where my little sister who was barely even ONE when I was watching this show, saw it and answered it CORRECTLY. It was [Tekka Man - The Space Knight](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0294200/).

The anime is called Tekkaman the Space Knight, which is a cousin of Tekkaman Blade, although they are two different storylines & characters. In this anime, the MC's name is Barry Gallagher (Johji Minami in the original Japanese version) who binds with a robot suit to become a Tekkaman to fight aliens trying to invade Earth. The main villain's name is Dobrai, who is the leader of the alien race known as Waldaster's, and has an evil henchman named Randrox (who is the alien from my post with the Gilbert Gottfried voice). The small alien mentioned is named Mutan & is a sidekick to MC.

Comment: It's great that you figured it out!  You could still make this a better answer by providing a brief synopsis (character names might help other people find this in a search), a link, notes about anything you remembered incorrectly...

Comment: For sure! So the anime is called Tekkaman the Space Knight, which is a cousin of Tekkaman Blade, although they are two different storylines & characters. In this anime, the MC's name is Barry Gallagher (Johji Minami in the original Japanese version) who binds with a robot suit to become a Tekkaman to fight aliens trying to invade Earth. The main villain's name is Dobrai, who is the leader of the alien race known as Waldaster's, and has an evil henchman named Randrox (who is the alien from my post with the Gilbert Gottfried voice). The small alien mentioned is named Mutan & is a sidekick to MC.

Comment: From the title of the question I was going to suggest Teknoman/Tekkaman Blade, so I was close.